# Splitting multiple videos into shorter ones at once

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to split my videos into multiple shorter ones, I've managed to make it work for one video, code is given below, but I have multiple videos saved in a folder and I want the code to go through all of them at once, so I don't have to manually change paths for every video, can anyone help?

````
required_video_file = 'Videos/Logitech/LogiCapture/1_stresni.mp4'

with open("times.txt") as f:
  times = f.readlines()

times = [x.strip() for x in times] 

for time in times:
  starttime = int(time.split('-')[0])
  endtime = int(time.split("-")[1])
  ffmpeg_extract_subclip(required_video_file, starttime, endtime, targetname=str(times.index(time)+1)+".mp4")```
````

Answer (score 0):

If all your video files are going to be in a particular folder

```
folder_path = input ("enter the folder path : ")
file_extn = input ("enter the video file extension like mp4 or mov or avi : ")

complete_video_file = []

#Below loop will iterate over the folder and get the list of video files
#and append the details into a list

for video_file in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if video_file.endswith(file_extn):
        complete_video_file.append(os.path.join(folder_path,video_file))
for required_video_file in complete_video_file:
    #have your code below
    with open("times.txt") as f:
      times = f.readlines()

     times = [x.strip() for x in times] 

    for time in times:
      starttime = int(time.split('-')[0])
      endtime = int(time.split("-")[1])
      ffmpeg_extract_subclip(required_video_file, starttime, endtime, targetname=str(times.index(time)+1)+".mp4")
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot, the only problem I am still having is that when loop iterates through new video it just overwrites the previous one with the same index; so basically I have 4 videos currently each should be split in 14 parts so I should end up with 56 videos, but I end up with just 14 parts from the last video (I know the loop iterated through every video since I have 56 successful prints)

Comment: That could be because the output file name could be similar and since it is in a loop the files are getting overwritten. From the code i feel it could be due to this 'targetname=str(times.index(time)+1)+".mp4"'

Comment: Yea it is due to that, but since I feel the sintax for that targetname is kinda weird idk how to do it properly

Comment: check whether the following links are helpful https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking,  https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video